# Select part of a string from a object type column SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

So shortly I am receiving an SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got OE.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP
00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s" when I am trying to retrieve a part of a string data.

```
SELECT dbms_lob.SUBSTR(cus.cust_address, 0, INSTR(cus.cust_address, ',')-1) AS output
FROM oe.customers cus;
```

So basically that's my statement.

The data looks like : OE.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP('322 E Michigan St','53202','Milwaukee','WI','US')

And I only want to display the city, which in this case would be Milwaukee.

However, the data_type of cust_address column is set to CUST_ADDRESS_TYP which is an object column of type address_typ.

I just want to select part of a string for instance, I want to only select Milwaukee from OE.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP('322 E Michigan St','53202','Milwaukee','WI','US').

CUST_ADDRESS  CUST_ADDRESS_TYP    Yes     4       Object column of type address_typ.

This is how it is showed in the table.

Really buggers me off as the statement works on varchar type columns but not on this one.

Kind regards,

P.S. Fixed it by using the object type column, didn't use Treat tho. Thanks anyaway.

Comment: I think you have to reference your city field within CUST_ADDRESS_TYP. cus.cust_address.city?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See object type request semantic in Oracle documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions198.htm

```
SQL> create type comp_type is object(
  2   x varchar2(10)
  3   , y varchar2(10)
  4  )
  5  /


SQL> create table t (col comp_type)
  2  /


SQL> insert into t values(comp_type('A','B'))
  2  /

SQL> commit
  2  /

SQL> select treat(col as comp_type).x, treat(col as comp_type).y from t
  2  /

TREAT(COLA TREAT(COLA                                                           
---------- ----------                                                           
A          B
```

Comment: well, I am still puzzled. I just want to select part of a string for instance, I want to only select Milwaukee from.  OE.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP('322 E Michigan St','53202','Milwaukee','WI','US').

Comment: You deal not with character data - table column contains object type. The access to object type data differs prom the access primitives like  varchar2, char, number etc. You should access object fields first. This concept similar to that you work with in Java. So you seems need to get data from third object column. You can use "describe OE.CUST_ADDRESS_TYP" command in SQL*Plus to get object structure.

Comment: @user3328073

select c.cust_address.city from CUSTOMERS c where c.CUST_ADDRESS.postal_code = 53202;